# Is there any way to make slider widget circular in shape?

Tags: flutter, slider, flutter-layout, customization, custom-widgets

I want to create a knob like slider so that i can increase the volume in my app. But the problem i am facing is it's by default linear in shape.

Instead of painting it, is there any work around.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that, you'll have to make a custom one or use some library.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [sleek_circular_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/sleek_circular_slider) package from pub.dev. It is much easier than drawing and creating custom slider from scratch